# How can I test my RESTAPIs IAP certification?

Tags: java, php, android

I am working on in-app purchases, and have set them up. I have created a script that should verify purchases (on my server) with google. I am having trouble testing it however.

Here is my server code:

```
<?PHP

$username = $_GET["username"];
$public_key_base64 = $_GET["base64key"];
$signed_data = $_GET["signeddata"];
$signature = $_GET["signature"];

if(!is_string($username)){
    echo "Username is not a string!";
    return;
}

$key =  "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n".
    chunk_split($public_key_base64, 64,"\n").
    '-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';  

//using PHP to create an RSA key
$key = openssl_get_publickey($key);
    //$signature should be in binary format, but it comes as BASE64. 
    //So, I'll convert it.

$signature = base64_decode($signature);   

//using PHP's native support to verify the signature
$result = openssl_verify(
    $signed_data,
    $signature,
    $key,
    OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1
);

if(0 === $result){
    echo "purchase denied";
    return;
}
elseif(1 !== $result){
    echo "purchase denied";
    return;
}
else{
    echo "purchase accepted";
    return;
}

?>
```

Here is my java code:

```
String result = RestAPI.getResponse("http://hg1.flarehubpe.com/purchasemanager.php?username=" + this.playername + "&" + "base64key=" + FlareHubVIPProperties.BASE_64_KEY + "&signeddata=" + base64encodedJson + "&signature=" + this.info.getSignature());
```

Every time I test this with the SKU `android.test.purchased` I get a failed purchased denied response. What could I be doing wrong? Is it possible android.test.purchased does not support RESTAPI vertification?

Comment: I don't see the reason you use this `1 !== $result`. You will get "purchase denied" for each value except 1, which is overlapping with the 3rd IF statement.

Comment: Isn't the success value 1? if result === 1, the purchase is a success.